# How to implement search using Query Builder API for partial search text in CQ/AEM

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have a requirement to fetch search results based on partial text match. For example, if there is a node under products say "apple-iphone-6" and the user enters "iphone" text in the searchbox, I should still be able to fetch the result.

I tried the below query on querybuilder and it worked:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/etc/commerce/products&type=nt:unstructured&nodename=*iphone*
```

But, how to implement this programatically for the `*iphone*` part? I am creating a query using the predicates as follows

```
        String searchTerm = "iphone";
        map.put("path", "/etc/commerce/products");
        map.put("type", "nt:unstructured");
        map.put("nodename", searchTerm);

        Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
        SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

But I do not get any results, reason being, the node name(apple-iphone-6) does not exactly match the search term (iphone).
But the same thing works fine in case I append * to the nodename value which then implements partial text based search in the querybuilder example. What change should I do in the code to get results based on partial node name matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have found the solution on your own, the [NodenamePredicateEvaluator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/NodenamePredicateEvaluator.html) accepts wildcard arguments, so you would need to surround the search term with wildcards, for example like this:

```
String searchTerm = "iphone";
...
map.put("nodename", "*" + searchTerm + "*");
```

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting that I have to do some modification and infact tried adding the * wildcard but in a different way which did not work out. This is working fine. Thanks for the quick resolution.

Answer (score 3):

in this case "like" opration can be used:

EX-> patial text serach for jcr:title

```
    map.put("group.1_property", "fn:lower-case(@jcr:content/jcr:title)");
    map.put("group.1_property.value", "%"+fulltextSearchTerm + "%");
    map.put("group.1_property.operation", "like");
```

Answer (score 0):

For just the nodename the answer posted is correct, but if you want to search inside properties as well  then :

```
map.put("fulltext","*"+searchTetm +"*");
map.put("fulltext.relPath","jcr:content");
```